# My app splash screen remains white

Tags: ios, xib, splash-screen, launch-screen

I tried to make an animation for the splash screen but I failed trying so then I deleted the code from AppDelegate, but when I run my project the splash screen is just white!

In the LaunchScreen.xib file I have a launch image but it doesn't show up. I have tried creating a new LaunchImage.xib file but is the same problem.

This part of the AppDelegate I used to apply an animation:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

I don't know if it was for using the AppDelegate but it is not working.

Comment: Have you ever try to clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: It worked, thanks! @JasonNam

Comment: Would you select my answer? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to clean the project and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Quit Xcode. Reopen. Clean and build. This solved my issue.